# Move app service from one app service plan to another (same resource group and region)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have two app service plans running in the same region, same resource group and in the same subscription. I have a web app in app service plan a, that I want to move to app service plan b. When clicking *Change App Service Plan*, the Portal tells me that "No App Service Plans Found".

App service plan a is running on Standard: 1 Small. App service plan b is running on Standard: 2 Large. Changing app service plan a to Standard: 1 Large, doesn't make app service plan b show up when trying to move the app service.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Are both service plans the same pricing tier? Maybe you can't move to lower service plan, because some features you are using are not available there

Comment: I've updated the question with that info.

Comment: @ThomasArdal - The simplest route is to just redeploy your app into the other app service plan, and remove it from the existing service plan.

Comment: it does, its an advice to just recreate the webapp, because that will be faster and easier. or not deal with the webapps at all. because they are what they are. overpriced, weird monstrosities. and you just confirmed it. btw your comment right after mine looks hypocrite, aint it? since you just confirmed what I told the OP

Comment: i never claimed you did. but the bottom line of your comment - recreate the  webapp. exactly what I said. because figuring out why that doesnt work will take a lot more effort because of the nature of the web apps. @DavidMakogon my rationale for that comes from 4+ years of Azure experience, I feel pretty confident about my feelings towards web apps. they deserved that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I found out why I cannot move my app service between plans. Besides resource groups, subscriptions and regions, there is a concept called Webspaces. As I understand it, a webspace is a number of physical servers within the same rack or something similar. In order to move app services between plans, the app services needs to be within the same webspace too.

Comment: But we have absolutely no visibility into these webspaces. They completely defeat the purpose of all this automation. It's like an invisible fence that prevents you from moving web apps to different plans and resource groups, making it impossible to organize resources. We have no control over what webspace a plan is created under.

Comment: Agree. It's fine by me that Azure split resources that way, but it shouldn't be a blocker in regards to moving around resources.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the webspace between the 2 App Service Plans. Are there identical?
You might move (multiple times) your App Service Plan to different Ressource Group but the webspace is based on your original Resource Group (when you created this App Service Plan the first time)

You might have also deleted your original Resource Group, so you might have to recreate it? (I have never tried this case, but it should create in the same webspace then)

To check I use PowerShell command:

```
Login-AzureRMAccount 
Get-AzureRmSubscription 
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId <Your Subscription Guid>

Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId "/subscriptions/<SUB-ID>/resourceGroups/<RG-NAME>/resources" | Select Name, ResourceName, @{Name='webSpace'; Expression={$_.Properties.webSpace}} | Format-List
```

For the name space, you will get something like:

```
Name           : Consoto_AppServicePlan
ResourceName   : Consoto_ResourceGroup
webSpace       : Consoto-SouthCentralUSwebspace
```

(Supposed that the location is South Central US)

So if you want to move your App Service to another App Service Plan name, you will have to create a new App Service Plan in the Resource Group named "Consoto" (refer to my example above) in the Location South Central US in the same subscription of course.
Then you will be able to use the Change App Service Plan functionality in the Azure Portal